Databricks vnet peering failed
My databricks is not Vnet injected and im trying to reach to Storage account that is in Vnet using private endpoint.
I have the workers vnet with public and private subnets.
In side the databricks workspace udner  Virtual netwrok Peerings (below image).

After checking Workes Vnet -> Peerings
i see this 
I am a contributor on subscription level. what could be the issue? and how can I fix this? found same issue here and i followed it but i cant resovle it Azure VNet Peerings - Failed to add virtual network peering between Azure Databricks VNet and Azure VM VNet
EDIT
I had to manually create the peering between my own VNet and Workers-Vnet. Then eveything showing status connected.

I had to manually create the peering between my own VNet and Workers-Vnet. Then eveything showing status connected.
But this did not solve my issue to reach my storage account from databricks tho
